# Is there a way to set property for UI only visible on storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I want to set property like text , background only visible on storyboard but not on real iPhone screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set some properties in a storyboard to better visualise your design in the storyboard itself, but then display something else to the user, you need to override said properties from code.

Comment: Sorry my question was ambiguous.
While it's fetching property from API, the text on storyboard is being shown. I don't want user to see that

Comment: @rob as I've said, you need to override the text from the code. Do it in `viewDidLoad`, then the user won't see it even while the real value is being fetched from an API. Set a placeholder text until the network request finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them in `UIView` in `Storyboard` ... and in `Controller` code `remove` or `hide` that view from your `controller` will not show that to `iPhone` user ....

Comment: Thanks!
I thought that would work too but it's kinda lazy to write 
override viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    label.text = ""
}
every time I make new ViewController
Isn't there a better way to do that?